# How to create a simple countdown timer in JS?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I have very little experience in coding in general, however, I still need a timer that comes on a pop-up that goes from 20 or 30 minutes to 0, and it should display the time remaining (like MM:SS). Then, when the timer hits 0, a new pop-up should appear that displays some plain text. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is very possible. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

This could do the work

```
let time = 5;
let element = document.getElementById('countdown');

function lower() {
  if(time >= 0) {
      element.innerHTML = time--;
  }
  else {
    console.log('popup')
    //open popup here
  }
}

setInterval(lower, 1000);
```

I did not do the time format tho. Only shows in seconds now